# Typesetting and typography related questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it acceptable to ask general typesetting questions on TeX.SE, even if not TeX- or LaTeX-related? If not (or maybe even if so), is there another or a better place where such questions belong?

For example, conventions for how to layout text in a document, indentation, etc.

**EDIT:** Based on comments, I'm trying [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76569/conventions-for-indenting-subsections-in-a-document-word) on Graphics.SE.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Could you make an example of what you mean?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe I should say "typography" instead of "typesetting"?

Comment: I understand what you mean. I think you should refer to the meta guidelines. Maybe these inquiries are irrelevant, but better you check by yourself.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou, I clarified that I mean on the tex site, not meta.tex site. Would the meta guidelines still (maybe) apply? If so, can you provide a link?

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't gone through it yet :). Just wait until someone gives you the correct answer for your question.

Comment: I don't think that such questions are very successful here, since they tend to provoke opinion-based answers or are just too broad

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ has a [typography tag](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). So you could ask there. Depending on what exactly you have in mind, one of the language SXs, Maths.SX, or Academia might also be worth a shot. If your question is very intricately related to (La)TeX you should of course ask here. The examples above however, will probably be a bit too broad for us.

Comment: Related: [Where do questions about printing go?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5803/5764)

Comment: @moewe: How about transforming your comment into a 'proper' answer? ;-)

Comment: @moewe TeX.SX also has a [tag:typography] tag, so OP could also ask here.  One has to keep in mind though that here one should ask about concrete implementations of typography.  For an opinion-based discussion there is also [our friendly chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Comment: @HenriMenke Mhhh, yes that is what I was getting at in my second-to-last sentence. Questions about typography on this page are mostly about implementation and sometimes about TeX-nicalities, but rarely about general typographical advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a [typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) tag on this page. The questions there though should be more about how to achieve certain typographical features in TeX or about TeX-nical typography (e.g. a question about whether to use `:` or `\colon`). More general typography questions are probably "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" here.

For more general typography questions you could try [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), they also have a dedicated [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) tag.

Depending on what exactly the question is about you could also ask at one of the language sites, [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)